# How to make a UNIX socket faster?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, unix-socket

I'm running a Google Cloud Compute VM as my application server for an app that's available on iOS and Android. The server runs Django within uWSGI, fronted with nginx. The communication between uWSGI and nginx happens through a unix file socket.

Recently I started noticing timeouts at client end. I did a bit of experimentation, and found that uWSGI sometimes errors out while writing data to the file socket. When I increase the 'max-time' parameter at the client end, it goes through smoothly. For example, a sample request that returns about 200KB of json data, takes about 1 sec for Django to compute. But the UNIX socket seems to take another 1-2 secs, which seems too high for a 200KB response. If the client is expecting a response within 2 secs, this often leads to a write error (as shown in the screenshot below) at uWSGI. When I increase the timeout at the client end, it goes through smoothly.

I want to know if there are some configuration changes that can make reading and writing on a UNIX socket faster. 200KB is a very minor size for a JSON response from my server - so I won't be able to bring it down. And I can't have a timeout of more than 2 secs at my client (iOS or Android), for business reasons.

[image: Screenshot from uwsgi socket intercept]

Comment: The first step would be to configure your uWSGI optimally since this is writing to and from the socket. Depending on the load and system architecture, you might want to have either multiple threads running or multiple uWSGI workers. Next, you'd tell Nginx to use epoll or something similar, and configure your uwsgi params eg the keep_alive, timeouts, buffers, send_file chunk size, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Several unix entities are represented by files but are no file at all. Pipes and sockets are examples of entities represented by files that are not files.

So, writing, and reading from a unix socket is not bound to file system I/O and does not share file system time responses. In fact, unix socket is one of fastest ways of IPC, being more efficient than a TCP socket, since it does not use network I/O at all.

That stated, here is some hints on how to solve your particular problem:

1. Evaluate your app for performance issues. Profile it and check where it might be spending too much time. Usually, I/O is the main villain on performance issues. Also, bad algorithms, linear searches on long lists are also common guilties.
2. Check your configuration on both web server and your application gateway.
3. Check processes scheduling. If everybody is running on the same box, process concurrency may be an issue for heavy loads. Be sure to have all processes running under proper priorities.

Good luck!